# error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Tags: xcode, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to commit on SourceTree, but getting the following error (completed with errors):

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
Please update your XCode to 12.4 before committing any changes.
```

I don't know what this error means and I am using Xcode 12.4, does anyone know how to resolve this error so I can commit?

[image]